# How do I use the result of a function in a string?

Tags: python

So like when you have defined a function and let that function run it will return a result, but how do you use that result in a string? cause now I'v got a bit of code that's like

```
def chosen_snack():
    while True:
        print "What's your favourite type of snack?"
        fav_type = raw_input()
        if "sweet" in fav_type:
            print "So you like sweet snacks? I'll give you a lollipop!"
        elif "savoury" in fav_type:
            print "So you like savoury snacks? I'll give you some crisps!"
        else:
            print "sorry, what did you say? I only have savoury and sweet snacks."
            continue
        return

chosen_snack()

print "What will you do, eat it or save it?"
choice = raw_input("> ")

if "eat it" in choice:
    print "Well I  also would eat %s" % chosen_snack()
```

like I want to let the chosen snack (so some crisps or a lollipop) be "stringed" by %s (Do I make sense?) but idk how

Comment: Your function doesn't return a result. BTW, you need to indent the body of the function.

Comment: To return a result you need to write something like `return fav_type` instead of just `return`. To use the result, you use `some_variable = chosen_snack()`.

Comment: I can't believe this isn't explained in every Python tutorial. This is basic to practically all programming languages.